# symbolicatecrash not working on fewlines

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash

I have created a sample application that prints the 4th element of an array(with only two elements). The application crashes as expected. I have the xarchive file and trying to symbolicate using symbolicatecrash. Only apple libraries like UIKit, CoreFoundation are symbolicated. Lines specific to my project are not symbolicated.

before symbolication

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001003391fc 0x1001f8000 + 1315324
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001003391fc 0x1001f8000 + 1315324
2   ...wiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib  0x00000001008f3344 0x1008ec000 + 29508
3   crashproj                       0x00000001000ec9b4 0x1000e8000 + 18868
4   crashproj                       0x00000001000ecaa8 0x1000e8000 + 19112
5   UIKit                           0x00000001874bd3dc 0x1874ad000 + 66524
6   UIKit                           0x00000001874bcfa4 0x1874ad000 + 65444
7   UIKit                           0x00000001874c3750 0x1874ad000 + 91984
8   UIKit                           0x00000001874c0bf0 0x1874ad000 + 80880
9   UIKit                           0x0000000187533414 0x1874ad000 + 549908
10  UIKit                           0x000000018773fd90 0x1874ad000 + 2698640
11  UIKit                           0x00000001877458e0 0x1874ad000 + 2722016
12  UIKit                           0x000000018775a080 0x1874ad000 + 2805888
13  UIKit                           0x00000001877428c4 0x1874ad000 + 2709700
14  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001832158bc 0x1831db000 + 239804
15  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183215728 0x1831db000 + 239400
16  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183215ad0 0x1831db000 + 240336
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181622278 0x181545000 + 905848
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621bc0 0x181545000 + 904128
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f7c0 0x181545000 + 894912
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 0x181545000 + 36936
21  UIKit                           0x00000001875285dc 0x1874ad000 + 505308
22  UIKit                           0x0000000187523360 0x1874ad000 + 484192
23  crashproj                       0x00000001000edd28 0x1000e8000 + 23848
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001805305b8 0x18052c000 + 17848
```

after symbolication

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001003391fc 0x1001f8000 + 1315324
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001003391fc 0x1001f8000 + 1315324
2   ...wiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib  0x00000001008f3344 0x1008ec000 + 29508
3   crashproj                       0x00000001000ec9b4 0x1000e8000 + 18868
4   crashproj                       0x00000001000ecaa8 0x1000e8000 + 19112
5   UIKit                           0x00000001874bd3dc -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1056
6   UIKit                           0x00000001874bcfa4 -[UIViewController view] + 28
7   UIKit                           0x00000001874c3750 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 76
8   UIKit                           0x00000001874c0bf0 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
9   UIKit                           0x0000000187533414 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
10  UIKit                           0x000000018773fd90 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4068
11  UIKit                           0x00000001877458e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1656
12  UIKit                           0x000000018775a080 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3134 + 48
13  UIKit                           0x00000001877428c4 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
14  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001832158bc __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
15  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183215728 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
16  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183215ad0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181622278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
21  UIKit                           0x00000001875285dc -[UIApplication _run] + 608
22  UIKit                           0x0000000187523360 UIApplicationMain + 208
23  crashproj                       0x00000001000edd28 0x1000e8000 + 23848
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001805305b8 start + 4
```

I am developing a command line application that would take crash file symbolicate it and do other processing. So I dont want to symbolicate using xcode's help.